# Call DLL function after loading the dll

Tags: c++, dll

Is there a way to run a function from DLL after it loads? So it behaves exactly like main() function. I load the dll to my application, and after loading the dll itself without any calls from application it's loaded to it executes?

Just like DllMain function, but it works when I inject the dll into an application. I want it to work  the same, but when I load it via LoadLibrary.

Comment: LoadLibrary calls DllMain function.

Comment: `If the specified module is a DLL that is not already loaded for the calling process, the system calls the DLL's DllMain function with the DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH value.`

Comment: Öf course, in `main()` you can do anything, but in `DllMain` you can do virtually nothing. You hold the LoaderLock during DllMain, and many functions can't be called while you have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DllMain` will be called in response to a `LoadLibrary`, but you are limited to what you can do within it reliably. It won't react well to inter-thread communication, as detailed in the [MSDN DllMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation. Best to put such code in an `Init` function. In my experience the more you heap in DllMain the more problems you'll have; do as little as possible.

If you *really* can't use an Init function then try creating a thread in DllMain (attach) and call your function from there.

Comment: Actually the question is how to inject code using DLL. So there's no `Init` function.

Comment: I reckon it's best avoided though ... if he/she must then I guess he needs to create a thread from DllMain. I'll put that in an edit.

Comment: I have all I need working in DllMain so just wanted to know how to execute it. If it's called by LoadLibrary it's great and that's what I need. So thank you for your help.